# Pricing for Google App Engine with Custom SSL

Tags: google-app-engine

Has anyone tried Google App Engine with a Custom `SNI SSL` Certificate? I have a question about pricing... Mostly everywhere it says `SNI SSL` cost **$9/month**. However, you have to have a **paid** GAE account to get SSL services in the first place. Here: https://cloud.google.com/pricing/ it says that the **paid** GAE account is **$9/month**. So I was wondering, does the **paid** include `SNI SSL`, or does that feature (coming from a **free** account) really cost **$18/month**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes enabling billing costs $9/month and an additional $9 for the SNI SSL therefore you will pay 18$ every month if you want SNI SSL.

and the VIP based SSL is $39/month
http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2012/09/announcing-new-pricing-for-virtual-ip.html